# Missing Permissions required be intent Intent.ACTION_CALL:android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, android-permissions

I'm trying to Call a number programmatically with the code provided below:

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},CALL); 
}
else
{   
    String number="56789855";                    
    Intent intent4=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent4.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
    startActivity(intent4);
}
```

I've set the permission in Android Manifest File as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"> </uses-permission>
```

Android Studio throws an error called:

> ```
> Missing Permissions required be intent Intent.ACTION_CALL:android.permission.CALL_PHONE
> ```

I can't seem to find why this error occurs.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel: "+number));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Everything is cool. just make sure you are importing the right `Manifest`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

Required `android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE`  instead of   `Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE`

```
    private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;

    private static final int REQUEST = 112;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
        } else {
             makeCall();
        }
    } else {
        makeCall();
    }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    makeCall();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to call.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

call function:

```
    public void makeCall()
    {
        String number="56789855";                    
        Intent intent4=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent4.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
        startActivity(intent4);
    }
```

Comment: How is that different ?

Comment: @NayanSrivastava Required android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE instead of Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE

Comment: Ah, I see. What you are hinting is he might be importing his project's manifest.

Comment: Just edit your answer a bit and let me pull back my downvote